# What is the preferred way for splash screen? - using handler or creating new thread?

Tags: android, multithreading, performance, android-layout, splash-screen

I am making a splash screen by [following this tutorial](http://androidexample.com/Splash_screen_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=113&aaid=135).

Here, the poster have mentioned two ways for creating splash screen.

**METHOD 1:** Create a `thread` and set time to `sleep` after that redirect to main app screen.

```
  Thread background = new Thread() {
            public void run() {

                try {
                    // Thread will sleep for 5 seconds
                    sleep(5*1000);

                    // After 5 seconds redirect to another intent
                    Intent i=new Intent(getBaseContext(),FirstScreen.class);
                    startActivity(i);

                    //Remove activity
                    finish();

                } catch (Exception e) {

                }
            }
        };

        // start thread
        background.start();
```

**METHOD 2:** Set time to `handler` and call `Handler().postDelayed` , it will call run method of `runnable` after set time and redirect to main app.

```
 new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

        // Using handler with postDelayed called runnable run method

        @Override
        public void run() {
            Intent i = new Intent(MainSplashScreen.this, FirstScreen.class);
            startActivity(i);

            // close this activity
            finish();
        }
    }, 5*1000);
```

I searched over the way abut could not found what is the difference between these two approaches.

Can anyone say me which is the preferred way in the context of use of resources and memory?

Comment: "What is the preferred way for splash screen?" Preferred way for splash screen is to don't create one

Comment: @MarcoAcierno Ya..I have read artical on this http://cyrilmottier.com/2012/05/03/splash-screens-are-evil-dont-use-them/   ...But it is for my college assignments and we are going to be challenged for most efficient code...If you know then please tell me.

Comment: @SaDeGH_F sure? I also read this article : http://samir-mangroliya.blogspot.in/p/android-splash-screen-tutorial.html and he is saying that handler is the best way. Can you provide a logical explanation about your comment?

Comment: @SaDeGH_F there is a BIG difference, and number one should never be used. `sleep` is NOT the correct way to wait for some time.  You should only use `sleep` if you **really** understand what you are doing.

Comment: @Simon why you making `sleep` so scary? I know that the real purpose of `sleep` is not for most of situations that are now being used but there won't be a super problem in using that just for waiting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Technically METHOD 2 (using handler) is the way to go. Method 1 calls UI stuff on a background thread, which may lead to bad results.

Answer (score 2):

Do you need your splash screen just to display a logo, or do you actually need to do some work?

If you don't have anything to actually process, Google highly recommends to just load the first activity.

If you have to do some init time work, use an AsyncTask like so:

```
public class SplashActivity extends Activity {

  private final static int SHOW_TIME = 1300;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);

    new LoadTask().executeOnThreadPool();

  }


  class LoadTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
      long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

      // Do the work you need (download resources, etc...)

      // Stay on screen for the minimum SHOW_TIME, even if we finished before.
      long remainingTime = SHOW_TIME - (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime);
      if (remainingTime > 0) {
        try {
          Thread.sleep(remainingTime);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        }
      }


      return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
      // Continue to next activity.
      Intent intent = new Intent(this, YOUR_MAIN_ACTIVITY.class);
      startActivity(intent);


      finish();

    }
  }

}
```

Comment: I need splash screen for animation while the application is loading.

Comment: as I wrote in the answer - if its just for logo, rethink if that's good for your users. Adding an answer in case you don't want to do anything but the logo.

Comment: @Guy, hi, i would like to get your attention to this question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35539960/how-to-get-release-build-apk-file-using-proguard, your help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Now, I found the proper answer based on [this search](https://www.google.co.in/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=handler%20vs%20thread.sleep%3F).

`postDelayed()` puts the `Runnable` in the handler thread's message queue. The message queue is processed when control returns to the thread's `Looper`.

`Thread.sleep()` simply blocks the thread. The control does not return to the `Looper` and messages cannot be processed.

btw, thank you Guy and all.

Comment: "Sleeping in the UI thread is almost always wrong" note that in your first example you sleep the thread you created, not UI thread

Comment: @MarcoAcierno sorry but I didn't understand. If you have better explanation for this,then please edit my answer or write in brief in comment so that the visitors can have true informantion

Comment: @MarcoAcierno ok..I understood and edited the answer...Can you say me now the above answer is true or not?